# Combining multiple pandas rows into a single record of different headings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of users with how much they spend each day. I want to rearrange them into just one row per users with the columns indicating how much they spend each day.

```
user_id   day    spending

111       mon      15
111       tues     20
111       weds     25
....
122       mon      44
122       tues     34
122       weds     90
122       thurs     26
....
```

I want to collapse the table into the form

```
id     mon tues weds thurs fri sat sun    

111    15  20   25   16    48  32  40
122    44  34   90   26    20  22  53
```

Right now this code initializes the daily columns (mon,tues,weds...etc) as all zeroes, then it puts the daily spending data in each column in the for loop, all except for the spending on that day should be zeroes, which results in a diagonal matrix looking table. Then I sum the whole thing up to get the all the values filled in a single row record. Right now this code works on a small dataset,  however the for loop is taking a long time on my full dataset:

```
for i,hr in zip(np.arange(len(df)),df['day']):
     df.ix[i,hr]=df1_subset.ix[i,"spending"]
# aggregate the users by id and dates
df = df.groupby('id').sum()
```

What is a way that I could use some more pandas-proper operations where I could avoid the for loop or make this faster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.pivot(index='user_id', columns='day').fillna(0)
Out[50]: 
        spending                
day          mon thurs tues weds
user_id                         
111           15     0   20   25
122           44    26   34   90
```

Or if you want customized aggregation functions, use `pivot_table`:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index='user_id', columns='day', aggfunc=np.sum)

table
Out[53]: 
        spending                
day          mon thurs tues weds
user_id                         
111           15   NaN   20   25
122           44    26   34   90
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use DataFrame.pivot to achieve this.  If you store the table in a dataframe named df then the code would be

```
Table = df.pivot(index='userid',columns='day',values='spending')
```